# Error 501: https page in iframe

Tags: iframe, ssl

I have an iframe in my page and I want to open https page (on other domain) with SSL certificate in the iframe. But when I try I saw a error 501 in the iframe and I can do anything. If I open the page when it is not in an iframe i get the standard red page saying the site is unsafe (in Chrome). If I click "procceed" the page will load as normal. Then I can go back to the page with the iframe and everything is ok but I want to prevent this error. I want my visitors view the page without doing this, without error message. How I can do it?